# Different image size in Multiple Screens

Tags: android, xml, size, device, cell

My app contain Banner, Body, and Bottom as shown below. The layout is fine in "2.7in QVGA, 2.7in QVGA slider,  3.2in HVGA slider BUT NOT in 5.1in WVGA and 10.1in WXGA". I tested this in both of my droid x and droid bionic, one of them has higher density (image 2 below), the one with higher density lives an empty black space. Does anyone know how to solve this so that both images will look the same.

Note: The one with higher density didn't stretch the image but only lives an empty black space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As always with layout issues: post the xml code so that we can see is actually going on. My best guess based on the two images: you wrap the width of the root layout. This will work fine until you have a device with a horizontal resolution larger than the images' horizontal resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the link, it tells you how to support multiple screen sizes

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html